# Burg boot loader themes are not working

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, themes, burg

My Burg Boot Loader in Ubuntu 14.04 , isn't showing themes.
I have Tried Installing Burg Many Times by different methods . but the themes are not working at all
They are not shown up on **burg-emu** nor are they shown during Boot Time.


Burg was working fine in my 14.04 until I tried to change the theme using **grub-customizer** , after that it is not working. Please Help .

Comment: I am surprised burg still works, it has not been maintained for ages. But burg writes its own versions of grub scripts and grub-customizer writes its own version of grub scripts. So I would not be surprised they conflict. You may just have to totally uninstall/purge  grub-pc and reinstall grub and if you really want burg. You must run these to move old scripts. `sudo mv /boot/grub /boot/grub_backup' and
'sudo mkdir /boot/grub' Then reinstall grub2 from scratch